# How to check the submission status of my Safari extension?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I submitted an extension for Safari a couple of days ago. How can I check for its status, and what is the usual process for an approval?

I checked on developer.apple.com portal, but cant find it anywhere.

Someone has asked same question on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-for-the-status-of-my-Safari-extension-approval) around 4 years ago, even no answers there.